# Configure Root MySQL access - MySQL Logrotate

Tags: mysql, logging, root, logrotate

I have followed the following tutorial [Configure Logrotate](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/monitoring-mysql-the-error-log-2009-09-16/) trying to set up rotation for our logs but I don't manage to configure Root MySQL access in order to flush logs without using username and password each time.

Logs are working fine but this step is not clear for me:

- I have created a new /root/.my.cnf file with the following configuration:

  [mysqladmin]
  user = root
  password = changeme

and set the following permissions:

`chmod 600 /root/.my.cnf`

1st question: should I put my root password or choose a brand new one (I've tried both)?

- I have then tried the following command:

`/usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs`

But it says:

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the thing, it was a problem due to the fact that the permission was actually not 600.  Now that everything is set how can I test if it's working properly? Can I manually run the logrotate to see if it's generating errors?